# Pipeline Loading Models and Tokenizers for Q&A

Tags: huggingface-transformers

Hi I'm trying to use 'fmikaelian/flaubert-base-uncased-squad' for question answering. I understand that I should load the model and the tokenizers. I'm not sure how should I do this.

My code is basically far

```
from transformers import pipeline, BertTokenizer

nlp = pipeline('question-answering', \
model='fmikaelian/flaubert-base-uncased-squad', \
tokenizer='fmikaelian/flaubert-base-uncased-squad')
```

Most probably this can be solve with a two liner.

Many thanks

***EDIT***

I have also tried to use automodels but it seems those are not there:

```
OSError: Model name 'flaubert-base-uncased-squad' was not found in model name list (bert-base-uncased, bert-large-uncased, bert-base-cased, bert-large-cased, bert-base-multilingual-uncased, bert-base-multilingual-cased, bert-base-chinese, bert-base-german-cased, bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking, bert-large-cased-whole-word-masking, bert-large-uncased-whole-word-masking-finetuned-squad, bert-large-cased-whole-word-masking-finetuned-squad, bert-base-cased-finetuned-mrpc, bert-base-german-dbmdz-cased, bert-base-german-dbmdz-uncased). We assumed 'flaubert-base-uncased-squad' was a path or url to a configuration file named config.json or a directory containing such a file but couldn't find any such file at this path or url.
```

***EDIT II***
I tried following the approach suggested with the following code that loads models that have been saved from S3:

```py
tokenizer_ = FlaubertTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODELS)
model_ = FlaubertModel.from_pretrained(MODELS)


p = transformers.QuestionAnsweringPipeline(
    model=transformers.AutoModel.from_pretrained(MODELS), 
    tokenizer=transformers.AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODELS)
)

question_="Quel est le montant de la garantie?"
language_="French"
context_="le montant de la garantie est € 1000"

output=p({'question':question_, 'context': context_})
print(output)
```

Unfortunately I have been getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\... ...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\nlp_nlp\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 105, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\... ...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\nlp_nlp\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 114, in _main
  File "question_extraction.py", line 61, in <module>
        prepare(preparation_data)
output=p({'question':question_, 'context': context_})  File "C:\Users\... ...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\nlp_nlp\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 225, in prepare

      File "C:\Users\... ...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\nlp_nlp\lib\site-packages\transformers\pipelines.py", line 802, in __call__
_fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
  File "C:\Users\... ...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\nlp_nlp\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 277, in _fixup_main_from_path
    run_name="__mp_main__")
  File "C:\Users\... ...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\nlp_nlp\lib\runpy.py", line 263, in run_path
    pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
  File "C:\Users\... ...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\nlp_nlp\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Users\... ...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\nlp_nlp\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\... ...\Box Sync\nlp - 2...\NLP\src\question_extraction.py", line 61, in <module>
    output=p({'question':question_, 'context': context_})
  File "C:\Users\... ...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\nlp_nlp\lib\site-packages\transformers\pipelines.py", line 802, in __call__
    for example in examples
      File "C:\Users\... ...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\nlp_nlp\lib\site-packages\transformers\pipelines.py", line 802, in <listcomp>
for example in examples
for example in examples  File "C:\Users\... ...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\nlp_nlp\lib\site-packages\transformers\pipelines.py", line 802, in <listcomp>

      File "C:\Users\... ...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\nlp_nlp\lib\site-packages\transformers\data\processors\squad.py", line 304, in squad_convert_examples_to_features
for example in examples
  File "C:\Users\... ...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\nlp_nlp\lib\site-packages\transformers\data\processors\squad.py", line 304, in squad_convert_examples_to_features
        with Pool(threads, initializer=squad_convert_example_to_features_init, initargs=(tokenizer,)) as p:with Pool(threads, initializer=squad_convert_example_to_features_init, initargs=(tokenizer,)) as p:

  File "C:\Users\... ...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\nlp_nlp\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 119, in Pool
  File "C:\Users\... ...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\nlp_nlp\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 119, in Pool
        context=self.get_context())context=self.get_context())

  File "C:\Users\... ...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\nlp_nlp\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 174, in __init__
  File "C:\Users\... ...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\nlp_nlp\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 174, in __init__
        self._repopulate_pool()self._repopulate_pool()

  File "C:\Users\... ...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\nlp_nlp\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 239, in _repopulate_pool
  File "C:\Users\... ...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\nlp_nlp\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 239, in _repopulate_pool
    w.start()
    w.start()
  File "C:\Users\... ...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\nlp_nlp\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 105, in start
  File "C:\Users\... ...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\nlp_nlp\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
      File "C:\Users\... ...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\nlp_nlp\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
self._popen = self._Popen(self)
      File "C:\Users\... ...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\nlp_nlp\lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 322, in _Popen
return Popen(process_obj)
return Popen(process_obj)  File "C:\Users\... ...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\nlp_nlp\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 65, in __init__

  File "C:\Users\... ...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\nlp_nlp\lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 33, in __init__
        prep_data = spawn.get_preparation_data(process_obj._name)reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)

  File "C:\Users\... ...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\nlp_nlp\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 143, in get_preparation_data
  File "C:\Users\... ...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\nlp_nlp\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 60, in dump
    _check_not_importing_main()
  File "C:\Users\... ...\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\envs\nlp_nlp\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 136, in _check_not_importing_main
    is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.''')
RuntimeError:
        An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
        current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

        This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
        child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
        in the main module:

            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...

        The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
        is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
BrokenPipeError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

***EDIT IV ***

I solved the previous EDIT error by placing the functions inside the "**main**".
Unfortunately when I run the following code:

```py
tokenizer_ = FlaubertTokenizer.from_pretrained(MODELS)
model_ = FlaubertModel.from_pretrained(MODELS)

def question_extraction(text, question, model, tokenizer, language="French", verbose=False):

    if language=="French":
        nlp = pipeline('question-answering', \
        model=model, \
        tokenizer=tokenizer)
    else:
        nlp=pipeline('question-answering')

    output=nlp({'question':question, 'context': text})

    answer, score = output.answer, output.score 

    if verbose==True:
        print("Q: ", question ,"\n",\
              "A:", answer,"\n", \
              "Confidence (%):", "{0:.2f}".format(str(score*100) )
              )

    return answer, score

if __name__=="__main__":
    question_="Quel est le montant de la garantie?"
    language_="French"
    text="le montant de la garantie est € 1000"

    answer, score=question_extraction(text, question_, model_, tokenizer_, language_, verbose= True)
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
C:\...\NLP\src>python question_extraction.py
OK
OK
convert squad examples to features: 100%|████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1/1 [00:00<00:00,  4.66it/s]
add example index and unique id: 100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1/1 [00:00<?, ?it/s]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "question_extraction.py", line 77, in <module>
    answer, score=question_extraction(text, question_, model_, tokenizer_, language_, verbose= True)
  File "question_extraction.py", line 60, in question_extraction
    output=nlp({'question':question, 'context': text})
  File "C:\...\transformers\pipelines.py", line 818, in __call__
    start, end = self.model(**fw_args)
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [the source](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/7d22fefd3726ea86902646c8fe23e157f44f0dec/src/transformers/pipelines.py#L320), there is a specific `QuestionAnsweringPipeline`. Below example is what I used to successfully load the Flaubert model.

```py
import transformers as trf
p = trf.QuestionAnsweringPipeline(model=trf.AutoModel.from_pretrained("fmikaelian/flaubert-base-uncased-squad"), tokenizer=trf.AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("fmikaelian/flaubert-base-uncased-squad"))
```

Of course, there is also the alternative to use the pre-trained model [`FlaubertForQuestionAnswering`](https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_doc/flaubert.html#flaubertforquestionanswering), since `pipeline`s just got released with the latest release and might be subject to change.

Comment: It seems the models are not there.

Comment: Can you clarify? I'm assuming that you are using the most recent version of `transformers`, which is `2.5.0`. Sorry, should have specified that before.

Comment: I even managed to execute the above code with my version (2.4.1), so it seems there is at least that bit of back-portability, although I am then facing an error with the model cards. Upgrading to `2.5.0` solved this problem and let me successfully use the model.

Comment: Just checked and despite updating I'm using transformers 2.3.0.

Comment: Thanks @dennlinger I'm able to load now but not able to use. Either when I try to fit both the loaded tokenizer and the model into transformers pipeline I get an unpacking error and when I try to use the QuestionAnsweringPipeline I couldn't find the doc as to how query it.

Comment: I'm curious about how to use that approach (p=trf....) To answer a simple question like: question_="Quel est le montant de la garantie?" and the following
    text="le montant de la garantie est € 1000"

Comment: I'm not sure if it makes sense to continue this discussion in this specific question. If the model is loading incorrectly, please update the question with the relevant error message, and updated version number. Otherwise open a new question and state your new problem.

Comment: pardon me, just updated the edit. I'm also googling this error that looks more related to multithreading.